# method with optional parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that has four parameters that I use to filter my data, sometimes the 4 parameters are filled and sometimes only three or two or one are filled, so I was looking for a way to take the necessary parameter values only. For example, if the user enter just one parameter like startDate I want to recover all the data with that date without taking other parameters as `null`, but it should not take them into consideration, my method searches the data which have the correct StartDate and the other parameters `null` I don't want do this

```
internal static List<Inconsistence> FilterList(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EnDate, decimal? State, decimal? Type)
{
    using (Model m = new Model())
    {
        return m.DBContext
                .InconsistencyDebtors
                .Join(m.DBContext.Inconsistencies,
                      u => u.InconsistencyId, 
                      uir => uir.InconsistencyId,
                      (u, uir) => new { u, uir })
                .Join(m.DBContext.InconsistencyDebtorDocuments,
                      r => r.uir.InconsistencyId, 
                      ro => ro.InconsistencyId, 
                      (r, ro) => new { r, ro })
                .Where(g => 
                       g.r.uir.InconsistencyStateId == State &&
                       g.r.uir.InconsistencyTypeId == Type  && 
                       g.r.uir.InsDate >= StartDate && 
                       EnDate >= g.r.uir.InsDate)
                .Select(g => new Inconsistence()
                   {
                       ParticipantCode = g.r.u.ParticipantCode,
                       DebtorId = g.ro.DebtorId,
                       InconsistencyTypeId = g.r.uir.InconsistencyTypeId,
                       InconsistencyStateId = g.r.uir.InconsistencyStateId,
                       DateInconsistence = g.r.uir.InsDate
                   })
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to learn a little about Overloading, http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx .

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What exactly don't you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write your where clause like this:

```
.Where( g =>
  (State.HasValue.Equals(false) || g => g.r.uir.InconsistencyStateId == State) && 
  (Type.HasValue.Equals(false) || g.r.uir.InconsistencyTypeId == Type) &&
  (StartDate.HasValue.Equals(false) || g.r.uir.InsDate >= StartDate) &&
  (EnDate.HasValue.Equals(false) || EnDate >= g.r.uir.InsDate)
)
```

I didn't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: it does'nt recognize g

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Overload.
Create 4 methods, each with a different signature which call the "main"-method, e.g. the method with full parameters. The Call goes along with some default parameters.

```
internal static List<Inconsistence> FilterList(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EnDate, decimal? State)
{
    return FilterList(StartDate, EnDate, State, null); // Call overloaded method with Type = null
}

internal static List<Inconsistence> FilterList(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EnDate, decimal? State, decimal? Type)
```

Option 2: Default-values
You can give your method-parameter a default-value. Only the last parameters can have default values. Looks like this

```
internal static List<Inconsistence> FilterList(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EnDate, decimal? State, decimal? Type = null)
```

This, the `Type`-parameter would be optional. When not specified in the call, it will have the assigned default value. In this case, it is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your parameters optional: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

```
internal static List<Inconsistence> FilterList(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EnDate = null, decimal? State = null, decimal? Type = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

`params` could do that for you, but you will need to down cast the values to `object`

Define the function as

```
internal static List<Inconsistence> FilterList(params object[] list)
{
   //check the size of `list` object and cast the values
   (DateTime)list[0]
   (double)list[1]
}
```

and the call would be

```
FilterList(DateTime.Now);
FilterList(DateTime.Now, 1.0);
```

Comment: On the downside, you have the boxing-overhead here, which is why I would tend to use one of the other solutions.